# Black screen after login ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, login, screen

Ubuntu 20.04

I pressed ctrl-alt-f10 twice yesterday and the screen went black. I didn't know what to do so I just restarted the computer. Now every time I login the screen just goes black. I looked online and some people said press ctrl-alt-f7/ctrl-alt-f2/ctrl-alt-f1, I've tried all these and it either does nothing or a terminal appears with 
user@login:

I've tried all the ctrl-alt-* combinations and other stuff on the keyboard but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

---

A slight update
I decided to press ctrl-alt-(and every character on the keyboard individually). Nothing happened.

I then decided to keep hold of ctrl-alt-(then smash my keyboard with the palm of my hand). I did this a few times, suddenly my desktop appeared.

I restarted my computer tried every button individually again and nothing. I smashed my keyboard keeping hold of ctrl-alt again towards the left bottom side of the keyboard, after a few hits I could see the desktop.

On the desktop I pressed ctrl-alt-f10 it went black
ctrl-alt-f2 came back to the desktop

On restart and logging in -> black screen -> ctrl-alt-f2 does nothing -> ctrl-alt-smash a few times logs in? I'm lost.

Comment: Anyone got ideas?

Comment: Ended up reinstalling Ubuntu as there was no answer for this anywhere.